# PHP: juggling with private and public functions in classes

Tags: php

I have a php file that contains a class and in it a private function.

> oldfile.php

```
class oldClass {
    private function functionTest(){
        // This is the function I need
    }
}
```

I need this function as a public function in another class.

can I somehow load the file into my new class for example with "include" and treat the "private" function from the other class as "public" in my new class?

> newfile.php

```
class newClass {
    
    /* 
      import functionTest() from oldClass as public function in newClass ??? 
      
    */
    
    from oldfile.php import oldClass public functionTest  // ???
    // or
    from oldClass import functionTest as public           // ???
    
}
```

Comment: Instead of trying clever tricks, if you need the function to be public then why not just make it public?

Comment: I have seen so many undocumented things ...

Comment: Private means private. You cannot access a private function outside it's class. Either make it public or make another public function that can access and return whatever private stuff you need.

Comment: Do you have access to make changes to the OldClass?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw no I can not , all I can do is load it.

Comment: @MaxMuster: You could use [PHP's reflection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php).

Comment: Ok, so the author deemed it necessary to make it Private. Why do you need to access it outside the scope of its class? Can you view the classes source? You might have to re-create it yourself if need be. Or have a chat to the author.

Comment: THank you very much. I understand.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw it is complicated. I do not want to change the software, I just wanted to add some classes and functions.

Comment: Thanks @David I start read it right now.

Comment: if you cannot access the old class, write a wrapper for it and treat it like an API. Do not mess with visibility. If two classes share the same logic, the logic has to be within its own tested!! class.

Comment: @pmk I would be very grateful if you could publish a small code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection to change its visibility, e.g.:

```
<?php

class oldClass
{
    private function functionTest($foo)
    {
        echo 'Private functionTest() called with argument ', $foo, PHP_EOL;
    }
}

class newClass
{
    public function functionTest($foo)
    {
        $method = new ReflectionMethod(oldClass::class, 'functionTest');
        $method->setAccessible(true);
        return $method->invoke(new oldClass(), $foo);
    }
}

$foo = new newClass();
$foo->functionTest('Blah');
```

You can cache stuff in class properties so you don't need to create a new `ReflectionMethod` instance every time, but I hope you got the idea.

Needless to say, this isn't something you do in the normal course of object oriented programming. It's a hack to deal with third-party code you can't redesign.

Comment: im curious on how you detect bugs caused by stuff like this... I highly recommend you not to violate visibility by using reflection + invocation

Comment: @pmk I totally agree, stuff like this should always be the last resort.

Comment: @pmk imagine there is a software you are using like CMS or similar, and you want to add some features. You cannot redesign the code, because latest at the next update it will be changed back again. So you cannot patch the code all the times. So you want to add code that works with the foreign code and does not modifies it.

Comment: Thanks @ÁlvaroGonzález

Answer (score 0):

its not possible, private method of class can be used only in that class

more examples are here
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php